# Changes to css in extend less not reflecting on site

Tags: css, magento2.4.4, less-css

I am using a custom _extend.less file for css changes, all changes are showing but this particular one. When I inspect from browser the element is leading with # instead of . So not quite sure what I should be doing here.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){

#zoid-paypal-message-uid_2944830117_mjm6mjg6nda {
    min-width: 350px;
    max-width: 1269px;
}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That element ID is rendered by JS, not CSS. Let's add a screenshot that shows `#zoid-paypal-message-uid_` element and the HTML structure like the one below, I'll help to change CSS.

```
root element
    parent element
        #zoid-paypal-message-uid_
```

Comment: See above is that what your after?

Comment: I don't see `#zoid-paypal-message-uid_` in your screenshot, please check it again.

Comment: See added screenshot above

Comment: You can use this CSS rule: `#pay-later > div > span` instead of `#zoid-paypal-message-uid_2944830117_mjm6mjg6nda`

Comment: That works thanks!

Comment: Cool, please the answer as **accepted**, it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.